# Laravel with Vue user backend and an AlpineJs admin backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

I am currently trying to build an application with Laravel, Breeze UI with AlpineJs (admin dashboard, '`/backend`') and Vue (user dashboard, '`/user-dashboard`'). I do Auth with Sanctum.

When I log in as admin, I get the correct admin dashboard but it automatically redirects to '`/user-dashboard/backend`'. This is because my Vue instance is always loaded in the `app.js`. Because my Vue instance has a router that has /user-dashboard as root. Is it possible to load two separate `app.js` and `app-user.js` files. Or is there possibly another solution for this problem?

**My Idea what can solve the problem:**
In my theory, you should be able to solve this using vite.  But I'm not familiar with vite.

**vite.config.js**

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

**my vue router file for the vue (user-dashboard) instance:**

```js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/UserDashbaord.vue";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "User-Dashboard",
        component: UserDashboard,
    },
    // ...
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.VITE_USER_DASHBOARD_BASE_URL), // user-dashboard
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->prefix('user-dashboard')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('userdashboard');
    });

    Route::get('{any}', function () {
        return view('userdashboard');
    });   

})->name('user.dashboard');


Route::get('/backend', function () {
    return view('backend');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('backend');
```

**views/layouts/app-user.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }} User Dashboard</title>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**views/layouts/app.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Admin Backend') }}</title>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900">
            @include('layouts.navigation')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            @if (isset($header))
                <header class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow">
                    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        {{ $header }}
                    </div>
                </header>
            @endif

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```